# Overlay of UIImage in UITableViewCell is not displayed properly when reloading the table or pop view back

Tags: ios, uitableview

At first view load it shows me properly like this:

[image: Before]

Then when I refresh table or pop the view back it messes up like this:

[image: After]

But If I scroll down when it passes off the table it comes back to normal.

I populate the cell like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    TableCell *cellTable = (TableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];



    if ([[_itemsOfPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[OCFileDto class]] ) {

        //Add swipe menu
        cellTable.leftUtilityButtons = [self leftButtons];
        cellTable.delegate = self;


        OCFileDto *itemDto = [_itemsOfPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cellTable setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        cellTable.cellName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
        cellTable.filePath = [itemDto.filePath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        cellTable.fileName = [itemDto.fileName stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)NSUTF8StringEncoding];



        if ([itemDto isDirectory]) {
            cellTable.cellImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b_ic_menu_archive.png"];
            cellTable.cellType = kCellTypeFolder;
            cellTable.cellName.text = [cellTable.fileName substringToIndex:[cellTable.fileName length]-1];
            cellTable.timeStamp.text = [self stringLasResponse:itemDto.date];
            numberOfFolder++;

        } else {

            if ([[cellTable.fileName pathExtension] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"pdf"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                cellTable.cellImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file_pdf.png"];
                cellTable.cellType = kCellTypeFilePDF;
            }else{

                if ([[cellTable.fileName pathExtension] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"jpg"] == NSOrderedSame ||
                    [[cellTable.fileName pathExtension] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"png"] == NSOrderedSame ||
                    [[cellTable.fileName pathExtension] caseInsensitiveCompare:@"gif"] == NSOrderedSame) {
                    cellTable.cellImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file_image.png"];
                    cellTable.cellType = kCellTypeFilePicture;
                }else{

                    cellTable.cellImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"file.png"];
                    cellTable.cellType = kCellTypeOtherFile;


                }

                /*============Check if file on local or not==============*/
                NSString *localPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentPath ,cellTable.fileName];
                if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath] && cellTable.cellType != kCellTypeFolder) {
                    cellTable.downloadedOverlay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadedOverlay.png"];
               /*============Check if file on local or not==============*/


                }
            }

            cellTable.cellName.text = cellTable.fileName;
            cellTable.timeStamp.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", [self stringLasResponse:itemDto.date], [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:itemDto.size countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleMemory]];
            numberOfFile++;

        }

        return cellTable;

    }else{


        // Show File Summary at last Cell
        if ([[_itemsOfPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[TableViewCellNoBorder class]] ) {

            if ([_itemsOfPath count] > 1 ) {

                NSString *tableSummary;

                if (numberOfFolder == 0) {

                    tableSummary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d files", numberOfFile];

                }else{

                    if (numberOfFile == 0) {

                        tableSummary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d folders", numberOfFolder];

                    }else{

                        tableSummary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d files, %d folders",numberOfFile,numberOfFolder];
                    }
                }

                //Summery cell
                TableViewCellNoBorder *lastCell = [_itemsOfPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                lastCell.textLabel.text = tableSummary;
                lastCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9];
                lastCell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                return lastCell;
            }

        }

        //No file and folder
        tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        return [_itemsOfPath objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

}
```

*** That line I use it to add a green arrow.

I debug it and see all the files that will add my green arrow is call properly but when it shows some other cell has that green arrow in it too.

I read around it said some thing about that cell has been dequeue and it loses their state and do something like:

```
if (cellTable == nil) {
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

But when I Debug it, they weren't called at all.

I don't know how to deal with it. Can anybody give me a suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, if you are using `if` statement in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` then make you that you also implemented `else` section for EVERY `if` statement. E.g. if you must set some image to imageView of your cell for some case, then implement `else` section, and set back imageView state for that case (I guess in your case you must set it to `nil`).
Especially ,when you checking existence of file

Comment: And why you call `dequeueReusableCell` for multiple times for same identifier? 
Check line `8` and `15`. 
You can erase line 15 at all.

Comment: @arturdev Sorry I forgot to delete it when I test `if (cellTable == nil)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Ok, after checking with more detail your code, change:

```
if ([itemDto isDirectory]) {
    cellTable.cellImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b_ic_menu_archive.png"];
    cellTable.cellType = kCellTypeFolder;
    cellTable.cellName.text = [cellTable.fileName substringToIndex:[cellTable.fileName length]-1];
    cellTable.timeStamp.text = [self stringLasResponse:itemDto.date];
    numberOfFolder++;    
}
```

to

```
 if ([itemDto isDirectory]) {
     cellTable.cellImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"b_ic_menu_archive.png"];
    cellTable.cellType = kCellTypeFolder;
    cellTable.cellName.text = [cellTable.fileName substringToIndex:[cellTable.fileName length]-1];
    cellTable.timeStamp.text = [self stringLasResponse:itemDto.date];
    numberOfFolder++;    
    cellTable.downloadedOverlay.image = nil;
}
```

I hope you understand what's going on. When you dequeue a cell, you get it as it was set up last time it was used. You have to clear everything up and set all the elements of the cell to display the new information.

**End edit**

Add

```
else {
    cellTable.downloadedOverlay.image = nil;
}
```

to the if clause:

```
/*============Check if file on local or not==============*/
NSString *localPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentPath ,cellTable.fileName];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath] && cellTable.cellType != kCellTypeFolder) {
     cellTable.downloadedOverlay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadedOverlay.png"];
/*============Check if file on local or not==============*/

}
```

Final:

```
/*============Check if file on local or not==============*/
NSString *localPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentPath ,cellTable.fileName];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath] && cellTable.cellType != kCellTypeFolder) {
     cellTable.downloadedOverlay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadedOverlay.png"];
/*============Check if file on local or not==============*/

}
else {
    cellTable.downloadedOverlay.image = nil;
}
```

This way, if you get a dequeued cell that had the image already set, you clear it up.

Comment: @KoKoHLApinyanont please check out the edit of my answer. I think it will help you.